# Issues with photoshop window on second monitor - yosemite

Tags: adobe-photoshop, macbook-pro, osx-yosemite

I'm using Macbook Pro 13' and iiyama monitor as an external one. Recently i've started having this weird problem. My photoshop window moves down - almost completely out of the screen on my external monitor. It's just impossible to work, because as soon as i enlarge the window and move it to the proper position, it goes down right away. Sometimes it works for a minute, but then when any dialog window appears in photoshop it messes up again.

Comment: There isn't enough detail for people to do more than speculate unless someone else happened to have the same problem and figured it out.  Super User isn't set up for troubleshooting.

Comment: Okay, so what information would you need then? I really need to figure it out somehow because i need to work... deadlines and stuff.

Comment: I suspect that this will be hard to diagnose from afar without extensive details about hardware, software, settings, what works, what doesn't, etc.; likely round after round of suggestions for things to look at and feedback to narrow it down.  Super User is set up for questions that have a known answer rather than open-ended exploration.  The closest SU comes to what you need is a chat room, but you need more rep for that.  A forum-style site would be much more effective at finding you an answer.  Look for a temporary workaround until you can identify the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem with my external display.

Comment: Nobody mentioned what version of Photoshop.. I'm having no issues with 2 screens & Yosemite/Photoshop CC 14 x64

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs on a Retina 15" with a secondary screen which is setup as a screen above the MBP. (Using Photoshop CS6)

What happens is that when you move a Photoshop window into the secondary screen it bumps it back to the MBP screen or puts it below view on the secondary screen (as if that screen is much larger than it actually is). When you try to put it into spaces it also bumps it below view making it hard to access.

The problem can be solved by either rearranging the screens, resetting display color settings or simply unplugging and reconnecting the screen.

The problem however keeps returning regularly.

To me it seems like there is a issue in Photoshop with multiple screens.

So far I havent found a permanent solution